# Algorithm for risky investments in banks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, algorithms, scoring-algorithm, risk-assessment

I made the following programming question on stack overflow but the users said it was more of math question. Here it is.

**Situation**
You start with a fixed amount of money, take it as $\$1000$. You have $10$ days to invest it in 4 different banks. You can invest any amount in any number of banks. The rates of interest of the 4 banks are $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$ and $r_4$. A thief is know to steal from these banks. The probability of him looting a given bank is given by $p_{(bank,day)}$, so $p_{(3,6)}$ would refer to the probability of him looting Bank 3 on Day 6.

**Notes**
He does not loot more than 1 bank a day.
Looted money is not compensated.
You do not necessarily have to invest money on each day, or invest anything at all.
Money invested has to be done so for a whole number of days, so $3\frac12$ days is not permitted.
You can (and should) take any level of risk, provided it is optimal when done on an extremely large amount of trials.

**Question**
Given all rates of interest and all 40 values of $p$, write a program that outputs the amounts to be invested in the 4 banks for each of the 10 days.

I don't think an optimal solution is really possible (in a few seconds), so even a greedy approach (or near-optimal solution) would be helpful.

Comment: My main problem is with the condition that the looter cannot loot more than 1 bank a day. Otherwise we can just try all $5^{10}$ possible ways to store the money (here he always either store his entire money somewhere or not at all). Edit: after thinking, this seems to still be optimal as well... I think.

Comment: That's a standard example of stochastic optimal control, and can be solved using MDP techniques; there are efficient methods to solve them, if you are interested I can elaborate.

Comment: Okay, thank you but no need. I am not exactly a mathematician, so I haven't understood the answer. I thought it was much simpler than this. Anyway, it would help others who view the question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the thief can only rob one bank a day becomes irrelevant when we consider large numbers of trials, as everything becomes probabilistic anyway. We can thus treat the probability that the money will be safe in bank $k$ between days $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ as:

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{money safe in bank }k \text{ between }n_{1} \text{ and }n_{2}]=1-\sum_{r=n_{1}}^{n_{2}}p_{k,r}$$

You can thus compute this for eack bank $k\in\{1,\dots,5\}$ and for every possible combination $n_{1} < n_{2}$, $n_{2} \in \{1,\dots, 10\}$, $n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$. To do this exhaustively we have:

$$N=5\left(\sum_{n_{2}=1}^{10}\sum_{n_{1}=1}^{n_{2}}1\right)=5\left(\sum_{n_{2}=1}^{10}\left[n_{2}-1\right]\right)=225$$

Which will not take long to compute at all on a modern computer. You can then calculate the expected return for each of these intervals in terms of initial investment $I$:

$$\mathbb{E}[\text{revenue}\mid \text{bank }k \land n\in[n_{1},n_{2}]]=I(1+r_{k})^{n_{2}-n_{1}} \cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{money safe in bank }k\text{ between }n_{1}\text{ and }n_{2}]$$

You can then compute all the potential expectations of having your money in a bank $k$ (or no bank) in possible intervals $n_{1} < n_{2}$, $n_{2}\in\{1,\dots,10\}$,$n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$. You can thus work out the maximum possible expectation in an optimal way (presumably there even exists an $\mathcal{O}(1)$ solution if you work it out algebraically on paper).